# IIS/Virtual directory related Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My site is mapped to the path `/application/Application/` in IIS 7.5. There is a directory in path `/application/Resources/` which is used to serve JavaScript and CSS files.

I have created a virtual directory in IIS under my site and mapped it to the `/application/Resources` path, but the JS and CSS files in there are not accessible.

How to access these JS and CSS files? I want to access them like `http://mysite/ABC/MyTest.js`.

Comment: why don't you put it inside your application?

Comment: have you hosted you js and css in a website if yes then what is the host name try to use hostname and then filepath

Comment: What is the `http status code` for your js/css request?

Answer (score 0):

Add a virtual directory to your site with an Alias of ABC and a virtual path to #3

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `IgnoreRoute` into your global.asax `RegisterRoutes` method should fix this issue

```
routes.Ignore("*ABC/{*pathInfo}");
```

The problem is that MVC tries to resolve your ABC folder as if it was a Controller/Action, which is not. By ignoring this route, it will not try to go through MVC's routing engine for this url pattern and it will route normally instead.